# Statistics about running running singularity containers

Tags: statistics, profiling, monitor, singularity-container

I'm new to Singularity (with a little docker/docker-swarm background). I wonder if it is possible to find the size of a running docker container? I think it is not the same as the size of sif file, right?
Also, are there tools/ecosystem to monitor the running singularity containers, and collect statistics about them?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can see the size of a docker image in the output of `docker image ls`. A singularity image will almost always be a fair bit smaller than the docker image it is created from, as by default the docker image retains all its layers and is uncompressed. You can use `--compress` or `--squash` during docker build to reduce that size, though you'll want to [read the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) about the full effects of those arguments.

As to the broader statistics, I'm not aware of any singularity-specific monitoring. Any general resource monitoring software would probably be fine, even [`pidstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pidstat) as a simple option. The main thing is that it should also watches the usage of the child processes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Estimating the singularity container size based on the Docker image can temporarily work with me because the Singularity container is already based on a Docker image.
But how can I solve it when the Singluarity container is not based on Docker? I need the size because it seems that the running Singularity container consumes more memory than Slurm allows in my HPC, and I don't have root privileges to limit memory of the container (as explained in https://sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/cgroups.html)

Comment: That's going to be more specific to what you're running in the image than singularity itself. Memory hungry programs often have params that can limit how much they use, e.g., `-Xmx` for anything run by java. Alternatively, you can try playing with `--mem` / `--mem-per-cpu` / `--mem-per-gpu` params when you're submitting your slurm job. If cannot increase memory available that way, request the number of CPUs that will give you a sufficient amount of memory. e.g., 4GB/cpu, you need 32GB memory, request 8 CPUs even if the application isn't multithreaded.